# Android ListView ContextMenu not appearing

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I have a CustomListAdapter. I have overloaded my OnItemClickListener and added a registerForContextMenu line for the position that i have a context menu shown.

When i select the Item that should show the MenuItem, the menu is shown. When i press the back button on the phone the menu disappears. However now what happens that the same Item in my listview does not receive the OnItemClickListener anymore.  Am i making sense ? I mean after the menu disappears, the same item does not receive the click listener. The items above and below receive the event as desired. I seems as if the Menu has disappeared but still is catching the click event ?

Comment: Where are you calling registerForContextMenu? We need code.

Comment: I am calling it in the OnItemClick overloaded function. Can u give me an email address and i will send you the file ?

Answer (score 1):

It's bad. You have to call `registerForContextMenu` in `onCreate` method.

So try it like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.contacts);
   registerForContextMenu(<yourListView>);
   ...
}
```

for create `ContextMenu` you have to override `onCreateContextMenu` method

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu cMenu, View parent, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo info) {
   this.contextMenu = cMenu;
   new MenuInflater(Contacts.this).inflate(R.menu.conmenu, this.contextMenu);
}
```

and for select items override `onContextItemSelected` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)       item.getMenuInfo();
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.c_odobrat:
         deleteContactDialog(info.id);
         return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

And it should works.

Answer (score 0):

```
        quickLinkListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id)
            {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName(Home.this, "com.myapp.toc" + Constants.ACT_NAMES[position]);

                if (position < 4 && position > 1)
                {

                    switch (position)
                    {

                    case 3:
                        registerForContextMenu(v);
                        ViewHolder.v=v;
                        openContextMenu(v);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        });

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_home, menu);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Video Type");
}
```

Comment: The Context menu appears the first time, when i press back the menu disappears but the item does not receive the click event the second time.

Comment: In the future, do not post additional information as a question. You should rather edit your question and include the additional information after your original question. This helps maintain the Q&A style of StackOverflow

Comment: Typo: do not post as an *answer*